# Счетчик и циклы for и while (Python) нужно написать счетчик

Tags: while, операторы, python-3.5

Не могу разобраться, нужно написать программу прикрепить изображение не могу, напишу так:

ввести n вычислить:

```
s=1/3^2+1/5^2+1/7^2+...+1/(2n+1)^2
```

с помощью циклов `for` и `while`

что я делаю не так?

```
n=int(input("Введите n: "))
i=3
y=1
z = input("Выберите способ 1 - цикл while, 2 - цикл for: ")

if z == "1":
    while i<2*n+1:
        s=y/(round(i, 2*n+1))**2
        print("S=", s)
        i+=2
        s=y/(round(i, 2*n+1))**2
        print("S=", s)
        break
else:
    print("")
```

P.S. Вторую часть с оператором "for" не писал

Comment: Не понятно когда прекращать итерации

Comment: @СтаниславГрот когда вычислим все `n` надо полагать

Comment: @slippyk так `n` не меняется

Comment: Для проверки: если `n` равно бесконечности, то сумма обратных квадратов нечётных положительных целых чисел равна `π²/8`. Значит достаточно единицу отнять, чтобы сумму в вопросе найти. Точное выражение для маленьких `n`:  `lambda n: sum(fractions.Fraction(1, (2*i + 1)**2) for i in range(1, n+1))` или приближённое для любых `n`: `lambda n: (math.pi**2/8 - 1) - scipy.special.zeta(2, n + 1.5)/4`, где `zeta()` это обобщение дзета-функции Римана: Дзета-функция Гурвица.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5
s = 0.0
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    s += 1 / (2 * x + 1) ** 2
print('{0:.3f}'.format(s))

x = 1
s = 0.0
while x <= n:
    s += 1 / (2 * x + 1) ** 2
    x += 1
print('{0:.3f}'.format(s))

# 0.192
# 0.192
```

Comment: Вы не написали строку для ввода n

Comment: @Cheepee это не настолько интересно